# Error in parser

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I want to parse this xml and get the result between the  tag... but i cant get the result my xml is

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><loginResponse xmlns="https://comm1.get.com/"><loginResult>true</loginResult><result>success</result></loginResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

The handler

```
public class MyXmlContentHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    String result;
    private String currentNode;
    private String currentValue = null;
    public String getFavicon() {
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {


        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("result")) {
            //offerList = new BFOfferList();
            this.result = new String();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {


        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("result")) {
            result = localName;

        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {

         String value = new String(ch, start, length);

         if (currentNode.equals("result")){
            result = value;
            return;
         }


}



}
```

Any changes needed

Comment: Your tags maybe wrong. Isn't nsxmlparser the iPhone class? I would recommend "sax" and "xmlparser" for that.

Comment: @Tim its xmlparser sry... tags are correct..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you found the start tag you are looking for, "characters" is called one or more times. You have to collect the data not overwrite it. Change

```
if (currentNode.equals("result")){
        result = value;
        return;
     }
```

to

```
if (currentNode.equals("result")){
        result += value;
        return;
     }
```

Or use StringBuilder to do it. Furthermore, you should remove this, it seems to overwrite your result String:

```
result = localName;
```

**EDIT**:

```
public class MyXmlContentHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private String result = "";
private String currentNode;

public String getFavicon() {
    return result;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    currentNode = localName;
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    currentNode = null;
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    String value = new String(ch, start, length);

    if ("result".equals(currentNode)){
        result += value;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How about the exceptions or errors you get in logcat? People always post codes or questions, but often forget to add the exceptions. But exceptions give vital hints to what's wrong with the code. For example I don't see `currentNode` be filled anywhere, and you initialized it with null. So probably this may be your problem, as you can't call equals if the object isn't initialized (read: `null`)

Comment: I added an corrected example. I think @Tseng is right, you never set "currentNode" and might get a NullPointerException. I flipped the if ("result".equals(currentNode)) to prevent this, set and unset currentNode when start and entElement is called and add the value to the result String every time characters is called.